# How to use Jdbi to create multi argument IN clause

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jdbi, jdbi3

I have a batch of values in a map and need to update a boolean column in my database with for rows matching both values in the map e.g.

```java
Map.of("a", 1,
       "b", 2)
```

the update I want to run is

```sql
update table set zoo = true where (foo, bar) in (:values)
```

where the map entries each get turned into

```sql
... in (('a', 1), ('b', 2))
```

in `spring-data` this happens when you pass a list of objects as a parameter but I can't find a way of making it work with JDBI.
I'm specifically using the non annotation driven JDBI.

I've tried passing lists, maps and map entries as arguments but it doesn't look like they're handled this way by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this using `bindBeanList` and reading the `Map#entrySet`

```java
var values = Map.of("a", 1,
                    "b", 2);

jdbi.withHandle(h -> h.createUpdate("""
    update table
    set zoo = true
    where (foo, bar) in (<entries>)
    """)
    .bindBeanList("entries",
        List.copyOf(values.entrySet()),
        List.of("key", "value"))
    .execute());
```